# Python 3, gspread, Authlib - cannot import name certificate_transparency only on Linux

Tags: python, import, cryptography, gspread, authlib

#### Environment info

- Operating System: Ubuntu 16
- Python version: 3.6 (inside venv)
- gspread version: 3.10

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Use `Authlib` instead of `oauth2client` with `gspread`.
2. Use the code mentioned [here](https://blog.authlib.org/2018/authlib-for-gspread).
3. Try to open a sheet using `gc.open`.

**Here is the full traceback:**

```
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385805 2019] [wsgi:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385811 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385816 2019] [wsgi:error]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385821 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385827 2019] [wsgi:error]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385847 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385852 2019] [wsgi:error]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385857 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385861 2019] [wsgi:error]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385866 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385871 2019] [wsgi:error]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385875 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/myapp/views/event.py", line 64, in validate
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385880 2019] [wsgi:error]     worksheet = gc.open("Event Validation Test").sheet1
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385884 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 123, in open
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385889 2019] [wsgi:error]     self.list_spreadsheet_files()
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385893 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 96, in list_spreadsheet_files
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385898 2019] [wsgi:error]     res = self.request('get', url, params=params).json()
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385902 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/client.py", line 73, in request
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385907 2019] [wsgi:error]     headers=headers
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385911 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385916 2019] [wsgi:error]     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385920 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/client/assertion_session.py", line 43, in request
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385925 2019] [wsgi:error]     method, url, headers=headers, data=data, auth=auth, **kwargs)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385930 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 519, in request
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385934 2019] [wsgi:error]     prep = self.prepare_request(req)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385939 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 462, in prepare_request
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385944 2019] [wsgi:error]     hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385949 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 317, in prepare
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385954 2019] [wsgi:error]     self.prepare_auth(auth, url)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385966 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 548, in prepare_auth
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385971 2019] [wsgi:error]     r = auth(self)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385975 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/client/assertion_session.py", line 9, in __call__
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385980 2019] [wsgi:error]     self.ensure_refresh_token()
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385984 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/client/assertion_client.py", line 9, in ensure_refresh_token
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385989 2019] [wsgi:error]     return self.client.refresh_token()
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385993 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/oauth2/rfc7521/client.py", line 55, in refresh_token
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.385998 2019] [wsgi:error]     **self._kwargs
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386002 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/oauth2/rfc7523/grant.py", line 24, in sign
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386007 2019] [wsgi:error]     expires_at, claims, **kwargs)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386012 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/oauth2/rfc7523/assertion.py", line 36, in sign_jwt_bearer_assertion
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386016 2019] [wsgi:error]     return jwt.encode(header, payload, key)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386021 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/rfc7519/jwt.py", line 95, in encode
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386025 2019] [wsgi:error]     return self._jws.serialize_compact(header, text, key)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386030 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/rfc7515/jws.py", line 71, in serialize_compact
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386035 2019] [wsgi:error]     self._algorithms, jws_header, payload, key, private=True)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386039 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/util.py", line 12, in prepare_algorithm_key
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386044 2019] [wsgi:error]     key = algorithm.prepare_private_key(key)
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386048 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/authlib/jose/rfc7518/_backends/_key_cryptography.py", line 19, in prepare_private_key
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386053 2019] [wsgi:error]     return load_pem_private_key(key, password=None, backend=default_backend())
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386058 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 15, in default_backend
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386063 2019] [wsgi:error]     from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386067 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386076 2019] [wsgi:error]     from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386081 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 18, in <module>
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386085 2019] [wsgi:error]     from cryptography import utils, x509
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386090 2019] [wsgi:error]   File "/var/www/abc.example.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386095 2019] [wsgi:error]     from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency
[Tue Sep 17 16:22:18.386099 2019] [wsgi:error] ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency
```

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Checked if the file path is correct. `certificate_transparency.py` does exist in `/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cryptography/x509`.
2. Tried the same on Windows, it works without any error.
3. Reinstalled all dependencies, including `pyOpenSSL`.
4. Tried importing it inside `(venv)` Python console. `>>> from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency` works fine.

**My code:**

```py
def create_assertion_session(conf_file, scopes, subject=None):
    with open(conf_file, 'r') as f:
        conf = json.load(f)

    token_url = conf['token_uri']
    issuer = conf['client_email']
    key = conf['private_key']
    key_id = conf.get('private_key_id')

    header = {'alg': 'RS256'}
    if key_id:
        header['kid'] = key_id

    # Google puts scope in payload
    claims = {'scope': ' '.join(scopes)}
    return AssertionSession(
        grant_type=AssertionSession.JWT_BEARER_GRANT_TYPE,
        token_url=token_url,
        issuer=issuer,
        audience=token_url,
        claims=claims,
        subject=subject,
        key=key,
        header=header,
    )

scopes = [
    'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
]
session = create_assertion_session(json_key_file, scopes)
gc = Client(None, session)
worksheet = gc.open("Event Validation Test").sheet1 # this causes the error
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an issue of Authlib. Checkout https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation/ how to install cryptography on ubuntu.

Comment: I followed the instructions there. I am still getting the same error. This happens only in a Python 3 environment though. I am able to use Authlib in Python 2.